# Does synchronisation with ConcurrentHashMap's .compute() guarantee visibility?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap, memory-visibility

Within `ConcurrentHashMap.compute()` I increment and decrement some long value located in shared memory. Read, increment/decrement only gets performed within `compute` method on the same key.
So the access to long value is synchronised by locking on ConcurrentHashMap segment, thus increment/decrement is **atomic**. My question is: Does this synchronisation on a map guarantee **visibility** for long value? Can I rely on Map's internal synchronisation or should I make my long value `volatile`?

I know that when you explicitly synchronise on a lock, visibility is guaranteed. But I do not have perfect understanding of `ConcurrentHashMap` internals. Or maybe I can trust it today but tomorrow `ConcurrentHashMap`'s internals may somehow change: exclusive access will be preserved,  but visibility will disappear... and it is an argument to make my long value volatile.

Below I will post a simplified example. According to the test there is no race condition today. But can I trust this code long-term without `volatile` for `long value`?

```java
class LongHolder {

    private final ConcurrentMap<Object, Object> syncMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private long value = 0;

    public void increment() {
        syncMap.compute("1", (k, v) -> {
            if (++value == 2000000) {
                System.out.println("Expected final state. If this gets printed, this simple test did not detect visibility problem");
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
}

class IncrementRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final LongHolder longHolder;

    IncrementRunnable(LongHolder longHolder) {
        this.longHolder = longHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            longHolder.increment();
        }
    }
}


public class ConcurrentMapExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        LongHolder longholder = new LongHolder();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new IncrementRunnable(longholder));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new IncrementRunnable(longholder));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

UPD: adding another example which is closer to the code I am working on. I would like to remove map entries when no one else is using the object. Please note that reading and writing of the long value happens only inside of remapping function of `ConcurrentHashMap.compute`:

```java
public class ObjectProvider {

    private final ConcurrentMap<Long, CountingObject> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public CountingObject takeObjectForId(Long id) {
        return map.compute(id, (k, v) -> {
            CountingObject returnLock;
            returnLock = v == null ? new CountingObject() : v;

            returnLock.incrementUsages();
            return returnLock;
        });
    }

    public void releaseObjectForId(Long id, CountingObject o) {
        map.compute(id, (k, v) -> o.decrementUsages() == 0 ? null : o);
    }
}

class CountingObject {
    private int usages;

    public void incrementUsages() {
        --usages;
    }

    public int decrementUsages() {
        return --usages;
    }
}
```

UPD2: I admit that I failed to provide the simplest code examples previously, posting a real code now:

```java
public class LockerUtility<T> {

    private final ConcurrentMap<T, CountingLock> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void executeLocked(T entityId, Runnable synchronizedCode) {
        CountingLock lock = synchronizedTakeEntityLock(entityId);
        try {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                synchronizedCode.run();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        } finally {
            synchronizedReturnEntityLock(entityId, lock);
        }

    }

    private CountingLock synchronizedTakeEntityLock(T id) {
        return locks.compute(id, (k, l) -> {
            CountingLock returnLock;
            returnLock = l == null ? new CountingLock() : l;

            returnLock.takeForUsage();
            return returnLock;
        });
    }

    private void synchronizedReturnEntityLock(T lockId, CountingLock lock) {
        locks.compute(lockId, (i, v) -> lock.returnBack() == 0 ? null : lock);
    }

    private static class CountingLock extends ReentrantLock {
        private volatile long usages = 0;

        public void takeForUsage() {
            usages++;
        }

        public long returnBack() {
            return --usages;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this approach will not work, *not even* with volatile.  You would have to use `AtomicLong`, `LongAdder`, or the like, to make this properly thread-safe.  `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't even work with segmented locks these days.

Also, your test does not prove anything.  Concurrency issues by definition don't happen every time.  Not even every millionth time.

You must use a proper concurrent `Long` accumulator like `AtomicLong` or `LongAdder`.

Comment: I did not emphasise in my question that the SAME key is used all the time for single long value. Still do not understand: why atomicity will not work for incrementing long value? Is it possible for multiple threads to stand inside of `compute`'s remapping `BiFunction` at the same moment of time?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, but that doesn't give you visibility effects.  Other threads won't necessarily see the update to `counter`.  Visibility is _not_ going to be guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Do not get fooled by the line in the documentation of `compute`:

> The entire method invocation is performed atomically

This does work for side-effects, like you have in that `value++`; it only works for the internal data of `ConcurrentHashMap`.

The first thing that you miss is that `locking` in `CHM`, the implementation has changed a lot (as the other answer has noted). But even if it did not, your understanding of the:

> I know that when you explicitly synchronize on a lock, visibility is guaranteed

is flawed. `JLS` says that this is guaranteed when *both* the `reader` and the `writer` use the same lock; which in your case obviously does not happen; as such no guarantees are in place. In general `happens-before` guarantees (that you would require here) only work for pairs, for both reader and writer.

Comment: Does your answer mean that `compute`s atomicity can be guaranteed by using different locks inside of `CHM`?

Comment: @Kirill no, I meant your `getValue` does not use the same lock that `compute` would

Comment: agree, my example for the question is definitely flawed regarding to reading of the final result. I adjusted the example. In my real code reading and writing of the long value happens ONLY inside of `compute`. Still no visibility guaranteed?

Comment: @Kirill I am confused by your edit also, you still have `getValue`... can you revise and present an example of what you mean?

Comment: `getValue` removed. Any read/write happens inside of `compute`

Comment: @Kirill still no, `compute` might lock entirely differently for reads and writes, internally. The method (so does the package documentation) does not mention anything about `happens-before` in this scenario. I would not rely on it

Comment: @Kirill your edits are not improving the situation but are rather frightening. Even if you happen to write an apparently safe variant, we have to assume that your real life case looks different again and any statement from our side would be misleading. The same applies if you decide to edit your question again and the answers do not match the question’s examples. Besides that, even if you remove the query method from the question’s code, you are handing out an object that would be entirely useless if no-one ever queries its state, so those (broken) queries surely do exist in the real code.

Comment: @Holger, I have to admit, that I failed to provide good example multiple times, the object holding the state should have been private, otherwise it is misleading. I added a real and complete piece of code and hope that now both: my motivation for such a code and the original question are clear. Any useful read/write of a long value happens within `CHM.compute`. The question is the same: is visibility for a counter guaranteed?